# Restarting service remotely as non-admin?

Tags: windows, powershell, service, permission-denied

We host (on Server 2019) a few server apps that someone else knows and configures the internal settings through a web interface or client application.  Occasionally, the manager of the application needs the service to be stopped or restarted because it hung or they made a setting change that requires a restart.  I'd like to give them a script to do that on their own time rather than wait for me.  These users are not able to log into the server.

As a sysadmin from a workstation, these kinds of PoSh lines work:

```
invoke-command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { stop-Service 'XYZservice' }   
Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -Name $Service | start-service
```

I've given the users "start/stop" permission on the services, and they (and not other users) can get the status of the service with:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -Name $Service
```

However, if my unprivileged user tries to actually start/stop the service, we get:

```
invoke-command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { stop-Service 'XYZservice' }   
[server.domain.edu] Connecting to remote server server.domain.edu failed with the following error   
message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

And:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -Name $Service | start-service   
start-service : Service 'XYZservice' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot open XYZservice service on
computer 'server.domain.edu'.
```

Likewise:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -filter "name='XYZservice'" -ComputerName $Server).StopService()   
Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

Is there some other PowerShell trick get this to work?  What use is the 'start/stop' privilege if it only allows viewing the status?

Thanks.

Comment: you may want to look into Just Enuf Administration - and perhaps the WebJEA stuff over on PowershellGallery.

Comment: Nope, not unless you go with what @Lee_Daily is eluding to or you grant the appropriate permissions to the user. Invoke-* , you need to be in the local admin group or have the perms to use it as designed. There is a reason for security boundaries/RBAC roles in Windows and Windows solutions.

Comment: Security boundaries are fine, but why allow an admin to use restart-service remotely, and block it for a user who has been delegated start/stop privileges on that specific service?

Answer (score 0):

@Lee_Dailey directed me to the most excellent solution.  [Following these excellent instructions](https://sid-500.com/2018/02/11/powershell-implementing-just-enough-administration-jea-step-by-step/) with a little more info [from here](https://4sysops.com/archives/just-enough-administration-jea-part-2-an-example/) I was able to do exactly what I needed.

Specifically, I included this line in the `.psrc` file:

```
VisibleCmdlets = @{ Name = 'Start-Service'; Parameters = @{ Name = 'Name'; ValidateSet = 'XYZservice' }},
                 @{ Name = 'Restart-Service'; Parameters = @{ Name = 'Name'; ValidateSet = 'XYZservice' }},
                 @{ Name = 'Stop-Service'; Parameters = @{ Name = 'Name'; ValidateSet = 'XYZservice' }}
```

and then my unprivileged user could do this:

```
$sesh = new-pssession -ComputerName $Server -ConfigurationName $ConfigName
$cmdString = "restart-service $service"
$scriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create($cmdString)
invoke-command -session $sesh -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
remove-pssession $sesh
```

and **nothing** else (except the related start/stop commands) on the server.

This JEA ability should be more widely documented.